# What is OpenVPN, What does it do on ubuntu?

Tags: openvpn

What does it provide exactly? I am looking for a VPN but nowhere can I find what OpenVPN is, is it for a different purpose?

Comment: Have you tried googling it for a start? You would likely found out https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVPN

Comment: how is it different from commercial VPNs like PIA is what i am asking

Comment: Please ead the wiki page, try to understand what it is and the, only then, [edit] your question by posting your actual doubts or points you would like to have clarified. As is, the question shows lazyness only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenVPN is a server and client application for providing a secure encrypted connection from one machine to another. The configuration is not entirely simple and you would need to control both the client and server. Usually this is to provide secure, encrypted and authenticated access to a server or network that you control. Often used for remote workers to safely access private resources within a business domain. There are other VPN services which do this, some of which are application built on top of OpenVPN.

What most people want when they're looking for a VPN is a VPN service, which provides the ability to use a VPN to connect to a server somewhere else in the world. Normally this is used to forward internet traffic from that server to your machine, you appear on the internet as if you are the remote server. Most VPN services come with their own dedicated client to connect to them and select the remote server, although it may be possible to connect to some services using the OpenVPN client. Some of these dedicated VPN applications are also built on top of OpenVPN.

This is usually done in order to browse the internet somewhat anonymously, or avoid to avoid some location specific restrictions. I say somewhat anonymously as most VPN service providers keep some sort of usage logs, and may be compelled by their local governments to turn over such information.

If you want a VPN service, you probably don't want to use OpenVPN.

Comment: exactly what i wanted to know btw isn't internet traffic encrypted anyway, why would one use OpenVPN

Comment: It's encrypted when using https, although there is a possibility of a man-in-the-middle attack if you're using a gateway that you don't control, like coffee shop wifi. Using a VPN in that situation can add to your security, as it secures the connection from beginning to end of the VPN tunnel (so only between the VPN client and VPN server), it also adds an authentication mechanism. This answer provides a good overview https://security.stackexchange.com/a/1480/68990

Comment: Often OpenVPN is used when you have want to provide secure controlled access into your network for only certain people. Anyone without the correct certificates on their local machine should not be able to get in.

Comment: @Arronical re: "If you want a VPN service, you probably don't want to use OpenVPN". OpenVPN is used by many VPN client softwares... so you DO want to use OpenVPN... it's just transparent by the use of the app.

Comment: @heynnema do you have a suggestion for how I could improve that? I thought that stating that "Some of these dedicated VPN applications are also built on top of OpenVPN." covered it. Should I say you don't want to use the OpenVPN client directly? Feel free to edit the answer to increase its accuracy.

Comment: @Arronical just remove the last line in your answer. OpenVPN can be used by various VPN client applications, but OpenVPN can also be directly used by the user to connect to various VPN servers, using .ovpn files.